# Converting int to Date

Tags: sql-server, date

How to convert to date in sql Server when i have data type int in my database?

[image]

For Example :
5th day in 4th week of 10th month in 2016

Comment: Once you solve this you should consider running away from this design as fast as possible. You should store dates in the date datatype. That is what they are made for.

Comment: So for the example values what should the result be?

Comment: Result : October 28th, 2016

Answer (score 3):

Use can [**`DATEFROMPARTS`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) function

```
Select DATEFROMPARTS(Year,Month,Day) as Dates
From yourtable
```

If you are using less then 2012 then

```
Select cast(cast(year as char(4))+'-'+cast(month as varchar(2))+'-'+cast(day as varchar(2)) as date) as dates
From yourtable
```

Comment: how i get the day in that month and year, if i only have 5th day of 2nd week?

Comment: @Student - Add sample data and expected result

Comment: 5th day in 4th week of 10th month in 2016
Result : October 28th, 2016

Answer (score 0):

This is a truly horrible way to store date information. It is a serious pain to work with and nearly impossible to validate. You really should use the native date datatype for this type of thing.

This produced the desired output for your sample. I think this is what you are looking for.

```
create table #SomeDate
(
    MyDay int
    , MyWeek int
    , MyMonth int
    , MyYear int
)

insert #SomeDate
select 5, 4, 10, 2016

select dateadd(day, s.MyDay + 1, dateadd(week, s.MyWeek - 1, dateadd(month, s.MyMonth - 1, dateadd(year, s.MyYear - 1900, 0))))
from #SomeDate s

drop table #SomeDate
```